# Write text with polyline

Tags: javascript, leaflet, leaflet.draw

Is it possible to write text or distance of polyline. I'm drawing polyline and i need to write text/distance for polylines.
i try [leaflet.textpath.js](https://github.com/makinacorpus/Leaflet.TextPath/tree/leaflet0.8-dev) plugin but it is not suitable for me,
How can i draw,something like this image.

[image]

Comment: orange arrow indicating the polyline and its text..

Answer (score 0):

You can add permanent tooltip to your polylines.

```
mypolyline.bindTooltip("ow yeah", {permanent: true});
```

I don't know what you want to do exactly but there is a "distance" method for the map object to help you calculate the length of a polyline.

```
var latlngs = mypolyline.getLatLngs();
var dist = 0;
for (var i = 1; i < latlngs.length; i++) {
    dist += map.distance(latlngs[i-1], latlng[i]);
}
```